# How to parse multiple XML elements which are not unique

Tags: xml, linq, parsing

I'm kindoff new to XML to Linq. This question seems really simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. Hopefully someone can help me out. I get a soapresponse like this:

```
<customernumbers>    
     <customernumber>99999</customernumber>      
     <customernumber>27554</customernumber>          
     <customernumber>27555</customernumber>       
</customernumbers>
```

And I want to parse this XML document in a list. I use this code:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load (@"c:\\mydata.xml");
var query =from e in xml.Elements("customernumbers")
    select e.Value;
query.Dump();

    5IEnumerable<String> (1 item)  
    999992755427555
```

Ofcource what I want is the 3 customer numbers separated. Not in 1 string.

Any help would be much appreciated.

//Phan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is basically selecting the value of your root node `<customernumbers>`, but the `XElement.Value` property will return the values of all child nodes put together exactly as you example is showing.  What you need to do instead is select each of the child nodes in a query instead.

To use the exact same format of your query, you just need to add one more `Elements()` method:

```
var query = from e in xml.Element("customernumbers").Elements()
            select e.Value;
```

`query` will now contain a collection of 3 `String` objects, each with the value of one of your child nodes.

If you have child elements of different names and you only want the value(s) of elements with a specific name, you can change this too:

```
var query = from e in xml.Element("customernumbers").Elements("customernumber")
            select e.Value;
```

Now `query` will contain a collection of the `String` values of any child element that has the name "customernumber".

You could shorten this up even more:

```
var query = from e in xml.Descendants("customernumber")
            select e.Value;
```

This will do the exact same thing.  This is much easier when you don't know the exact structure of the XML or it is very complicated.  The downside is it will select any child, grandchild, or any other node that has the name "customernumber" regardless of the location within the XML tree, so if you have multiple different nodes with a `<customernumber>` tag that you do not want to select, this approach will not work correctly.

Comment: This clarifies alot. Thank you for the elaborate response

Answer (score 1):

Try this to iterate child elements:

```
    var query = from e in xml.Element("customernumbers").Elements("customernumber")
                select e.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
List<string> customerNumbers = (from e in xmlelement.Elements("customernumber")
                    select e.Value).ToList<string>();
```